Change FMX TStringGrid specific cell background color
I need to change the background color of a specific TStringGrid cell with C++Builder. I find nothing helpful in documentation or other sources for C++Builder (not Delphi).
Let's say I have a TStringGrid (10 x 50) sg, and I need to change (example) the cell (row=3,col=5) in Red when I click on a TColorComboBox where 'Red' is selected (other cells stay unchanged).
How to do that?

The C++Builder solution is this:

The interface:

The C++ code:

    void __fastcall TfCollections::func_y_fxDrawColumnCell(TObject *Sender, TCanvas * const Canvas,
              TColumn * const Column, const TRectF &Bounds, const int Row,
              const TValue &Value, const TGridDrawStates State)
    {
        //Skip the job when the cells are not the desired "Colors" cells (index=1):
        if(Column!=colorView || func_y_fx->Cells[1][Row]=="") return;
        //Obtain the ARGB value from the "Colors" column:
        TAlphaColor argb = StringToAlphaColor(func_y_fx->Cells[1][Row]);
        //Define the desired brush and fills the appropriate rectangle:
        TBrush *bgBrush = new TBrush(TBrushKind::Solid, argb);
        Canvas->FillRect(Bounds, 1, bgBrush);
        //Complete the drawing of the cell with the color name:
        Column->DefaultDrawCell(Canvas, Bounds, Row, Value, State);
        delete(bgBrush);//Free the dynamically created brush
    }//-----------------------------------------------------------
    
    //By clicking on a row, we pick color from a TColorComboBox, and we place the
    //desired color in the "Colors" column, as a color name string:
    void __fastcall TfCollections::func_y_fxSelectCell(TObject *Sender, const int ACol,
              const int ARow, bool &CanSelect)
    {
        //Pick the desired color from a TColorComboBox:
        TAlphaColor argb = comboColors->Color;//Four channels Alpha,R,G,B
        auto str = AlphaColorToString(argb);//Translated into a String
        //Colors column index is '1' :
        func_y_fx->Cells[1][ARow] = str;//The string being placed in the "Colors" cell.
        //Place the Hexadecimal value in another column:
        auto i = (unsigned int)(argb);
        func_y_fx->Cells[2][ARow] = Format("%x", i);
    }//------------------------------------------------------------


C++Builder and Delphi share common libraries, so any solution you find for Delphi will typically work for C++Builder as well.

I do not succeeded to adapt these Delphi solutions. I know them, and I could not. So this mean that any question for C++ builder is flagged as duplicate.. Great. Would not it be more productive to help ?

"I do not succeeded to adapt these Delphi solutions" - why not? What stopped you, exactly?

I put this in a onDrawColumnCell event:
TBrush *bgBrush = new TBrush(TBrushKind::Solid,comboColors->Color);
Canvas->FillRect(Bounds, 1, bgBrush);
bgBrush->Free();
Column->DefaultDrawCell(Canvas, Bounds, Row, Value, State);
What I obtain is a half grid painted with the desired color, and then, the next click draws totally with the same color... what I need is the specific cell painted, and the rest stays as default.

Do not call Free() in C++. You are using new to create the TBrush, so use delete to free it. In any case, your drawing code is not differentiating which cell is being painted when the event is fired, so you are painting ALL cells the same color. Since you want individual cell colors, you have to keep track of them yourself, such as in a separate 2D array. When the TColorComboBox is changed, update the array element(s) for the desired cell(s), then invalidate the TStringGrid to trigger a repaint. Use the colors in your array to paint each cell in the OnDrawColumnCell event.

Thank you for advice. I still continue to dig... If I succeed I will give the solution to the C++ builder community. Since it's a 'duplicate'...
